# emails won't send to certain recipients in php

Tags: php, email

I have a registration activation email that needs to be sent out. It sends out fine to gmail, yahoo and the other well known email handlers. However, it won't send to .edu and some other less well known extensions. Is it something that is caused on my side or something on the other side blocking emails with certain characteristics. I am emailing a link after all.

Comment: maybe some edu sites have filters to filer non-edu email.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe that it won't send to **any** `.edu` domains, maybe just the few you tried. Have you checked your mail logs to see what happens when it tries to send the messges?

Answer (score 0):

This can have several reasons:

1. Your sending Mailserver is blacklisted.
2. Your PTR-Record is different from the A-Record of your Server.
3. The receiving Mailserver denies the Mail, because of the incoming Firewall rules or the Mailserver settings.

For number one you can take a look if your Server is blacklisted: http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx
For number two you can check your PTR-Record: http://mxtoolbox.com/ReverseLookup.aspx 
If the reverse lookup is different from your A-Record you can bypass this in your Mailserver settings, while you change the banner to the output of the reverse lookup.
I hope this helps :-)